# Deferred Result in Spring MVC returning incorrect response

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am using spring mvc 3.2.4 and jquery 1.9.0 for long polling. My application is deployed on Tomcat 7.0.42. My spring configuration files are as below:

Application Web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"   
  version="3.0">

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>

        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>

        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/app-servlet.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

</web-app>
```

Spring Configration xml as:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">
        <context:annotation-config/>
        <mvc:annotation-driven/>  
        <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
        <context:component-scan base-package="com.webchat"/>
        <bean id="defferedResult" class="com.exp.DeferredResultContainer"></bean>
</beans>
```

Controller for Posting data looks as

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/postComment", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String postComment(HttpServletRequest request) {
    deferredResultContainer.updateAllResults(request.getParameter("comment"));
    return "success";
}
```

Deferred Result container class

```
public class DeferredResultContainer {
    private final Set<DeferredResult<String>> deferredResults =   Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<DeferredResult<String>>() ); 

    public void put(DeferredResult<String> deferredResult){ 
        deferredResults.add(deferredResult); 
    } 

    public void updateAllResults(String value){
        for (DeferredResult<String> deferredResult : deferredResults){ 
            deferredResult.setResult(value); 
        }
    }

    public void remove(DeferredResult<String> deferredResult){ 
        deferredResults.remove(deferredResult); 
    } 

    public int determineSize(){
        return deferredResults.size();
    }
}
```

Controller for Deferred Result looks as

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/getComments", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 @ResponseBody
 public DeferredResult<String> getComments() throws Exception{
     final DeferredResult<String> deferredResult= new DeferredResult<String>(); 
     deferredResultContainer.put(deferredResult);
     deferredResult.onTimeout(new Runnable() {

         @Override public void run() {
             deferredResultContainer.remove(deferredResult);
         }
     });

     deferredResult.onCompletion(new Runnable() { 
         @Override public void run() { 
             deferredResultContainer.remove(deferredResult); 
         } 
     });
     return deferredResult;
 }
```

When I am trying to long poll it through ajax i am getting following response :-

```
{"setOrExpired":false}
```

And onCompletion method is also not getting executed.

To Simply things below controller gives perfect response as
{"1":"2"}

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test1", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public Map test1() throws Exception{
     Map m1 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
     m1.put("1", "2");
     return m1;
}
```

Once i change it to below and add Deferred result i get response as
{"setOrExpired":true}

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public DeferredResult<Map> test() throws Exception{
    DeferredResult<Map> result = new DeferredResult<Map>();
     Map m1 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
     m1.put("1", "2");
     result.setResult(m1);
     return result;
}
```

Polling code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    longPoll();

    function longPoll(){
         $.support.cors = true;
        var path = "http://localhost:8080/WebChatExp/rest";
         $.ajax({
            url: path + "/getComments",
            cache:false,
            success: function(data){
                //To Do
                            alert("Data" + JSON.stringify(data));
            },
            error: function(err, status, errorThrown ) {

            },
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            complete: longPoll,
            timeout: 60000 // timeout every one minute
        }); 
    }
```

I have searched various examples but cannot figure out if any extra configuration is required for deferred result. Please advise.

Comment: Have you tried debugging ? and check whether requests comes to 'getComments()' ? And what is Response type ? is it json or ?

Comment: You can use rest client for debugging (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/restclient/) and show us what you got.

Comment: Firebug is also another one :)

Comment: Where is your polling code using ajax?

Comment: @ keerthi, Jaya i have added the polling code and yes the service is getting hit properly its the response not coming in correct format as soon as i add return type as deferred result

Comment: What the point to use defferdresult without using another thread to fill it?

Comment: can you post the source code for DeferredResult?

Comment: For one, get rid of your `contextConfigLocation` `context-param`. You're currently loading your context configuration twice.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. Review your `app-servlet.xml`. I don't think it's what you've posted here. What else do you have in the package `com.webchat`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response body you are getting

```
{"setOrExpired":true}
```

indicates that Spring serialized your [`DeferredResult`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/async/DeferredResult.html) (which has various properties including `setOrExpired`) to JSON instead of handling it with a [`DeferredResultMethodReturnValueHandler`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/DeferredResultMethodReturnValueHandler.html). In other words, it used another `HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler`, most likely [`RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.html) (which handles `@ResponseBody`), to handle the value returned from your `@RequestMapping` annotated handler method. (The simplest way to test this is to see what happens when you remove the `@ResponseBody` annotation.)

Looking at the [3.2.x source code of `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/3.2.x/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java#L573), which registers the default `HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler` instances, the `DeferredResultMethodReturnValueHandler` is registered before `RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor` and therefore will handle the `DeferredResult` return value first.

Since you're seeing different behavior, we must assume your configuration is not what you've shown here. (Note that `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` registers a `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter`.)

---

Also note that you are currently loading the configuration in `/WEB-INF/app-servlet.xml` twice, once by the `ContextLoaderListener` and once by the `DispatcherServlet`.

Get rid of your `ContextLoaderListener` and the corresponding `context-param` entirely. They are not needed in your example.

Answer (score 1):

I know is impossible to be the problem in this case (spring mvc 3.2.4) but just for future references:
I get the same issue with spring boot 2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT (spring 5.1.5).
This error happens when you try to return DeferredResult using webflux instead of the traditional spring mvc app. Remember, in the new webflux api you should use mono/flux, not DeferredResult.